# add another turtle's id to another turtle's attribute

Tags: netlogo

In the model below, a bank can only fund customers with a credit score that matches the scores in their `acceptable_scores` attribute. and if it doesn't match any of the banks `acceptable_scores` it is rejected.

```
globals [
  scores
]
breed [ customers customer ]
breed [ banks bank ]

customers-own [
  loan_amount
  credit_score
  status
]

banks-own [
  acceptable_scores
  list_of_customers
]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set pcolor 8 ]
  set scores n-values 10 [random 900 + 10]
  create-customers 100 [
    set loan_amount random-exponential 20000
    set credit_score one-of scores
    set status "applied"
  ]

  create-banks 10 [
    set acceptable_scores n-of (random 3 + 1) scores
    set list_of_customers []
  ]

  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask one-of banks [
    fund-loan
    reject-loan
  ]
  tick
end

to fund-loan
  let person one-of customers-here with [
      (member? credit_score [acceptable_scores] of myself)
  ]

  if person != nobody  [
    ask person [ 
      set status "funded"
    ]
    set list_of_customers lput person list_of_customers
  ]
end

to reject-loan
  let person one-of customers-here with [
      (not member? credit_score [acceptable_scores] of myself)
  ]

  if person != nobody  [
    ask person [ 
      set status "funded"
    ]
    set list_of_customers lput person list_of_customers
    output-print list_of_customers
  ]
end
```

I want to add each funded customer to the `list_of_customers` after funding here:

```
set list_of_customers lput person list_of_customers
```

but the list is always empty when printed out. What is the right way to add another turtle's id to another turtle's attribute? In general, is this the best way to handle the funding and rejection procedures? Can it be done in one function?

Comment: The code as you have provided it, works for me.  Each bank's list of customers grows.  But, you have each bank look first for a customer to fund, but don't check to see whether that customer is already funded, and then look for a customer to reject (and I think you want to set the status of that customer to "non_funded").  Would it be more realistic to simply choose a non funded customer and decide whether to accept or reject them?  Also, are rejected customers still customers?  And finally, is there a reason for using a list of customers rather than an agentset of customers?

Comment: @Charles reject customers are no longer customers. I'm new to NetLogo and haven't looked into agentset, I'll try that out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pared-down version of your model using agentsets.  The bank behavior may not be just what you want, but it should get you started.

```
globals [
  scores
]
breed [ customers customer ]
breed [ banks bank ]

customers-own [
  loan_amount
  credit_score
  status
]

banks-own [
  acceptable_scores
  my_customers
]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set pcolor 8 ]
  set scores n-values 10 [random 900 + 10]
  create-customers 100 [
    set loan_amount random-exponential 20000
    set credit_score one-of scores
    set status "applied"
  ]

  create-banks 10 [
    set acceptable_scores n-of (random 3 + 1) scores
    set my_customers no-turtles
  ]

  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask banks [
    fund-loan
  ]


  ask banks [ show my_customers ]
  tick
end

to fund-loan
  let person one-of customers-here 
  ifelse (member? [credit_score] of person acceptable_scores) and ([status] of person != "funded")  [
    ask person [
      set status "funded"
    ]
    set my_customers (turtle-set person my_customers)
  ]
  [
    ask person [
      set status "rejected"
    ]
  ]
end
```